# Tomcat7 em cluster não replica sessão

Tags: java, session, tomcat, replicação

Tenho um Ubuntu com 2 Tomcat7 com as configurações de cluster a seguir:

O balanceador é o Apache MOD_JK.

**SERVER.XML:**

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="no0">
    <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
             channelSendOptions="8">
      <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
               expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
               notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
      <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                    address="228.0.0.4"
                    port="45564"
                    frequency="500"
                    dropTime="30000"/>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address="10.0.2.15"
                  port="4001"
                  autoBind="100"
                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                  maxThreads="6"/>
        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
          <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpPingInterceptor"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
      </Channel>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=""/>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
      <!--Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                tempDir="/home/nilson/war-temp/"
                deployDir="/home/nilson/war-deploy/"
                watchDir="/home/nilson/war-listen/"
                watchEnabled="false"/-->
      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
    </Cluster>
```

No server.xml do tomcat2, as portas são 8105, 8109 e 8180 e o jvmRoute="no1" e port="4002"

**WORKERS.PROPERTIES:**

```
worker.list=no0, no1, cluster

worker.cluster.type=lb
worker.cluster.balance_workers=no0, no1
worker.cluster.sticky_session=1

worker.no0.type=ajp13
worker.no0.host=localhost
worker.no0.port=8009
worker.no0.lbfactor=1

worker.no1.type=ajp13
worker.no1.host=localhost
worker.no1.port=8109
worker.no1.lbfactor=1
```

**ROUTE**

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**LOCAL IP**

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d2:22:ac  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fed2:22ac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:54502 (54.5 KB)  TX bytes:19774 (19.7 KB)
```

**FIREWALL OFF**

```
$sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**CLUSTERS LOG**

**TOMCAT1-CLUSTER.LOG:**

```
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.io.BufferPool getBufferPool
INFO: Created a buffer pool with max size:104857600 bytes of type:org.apache.catalina.tribes.io.BufferPool15Impl
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask remoteEof
FINE: Channel closed on the remote end, disconnecting
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector messageReceived
FINE: Received a failure detector packet:ClusterData[src=org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=8042, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]; id={-39 25 76 13 -106 98 73 -81 -72 -23 -18 -121 -28 -86 -44 -86 }; sent=2014-10-29 14:08:13.317]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:14 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl memberDataReceived
FINE: Mcast add member org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4002,{10, 0, 2, 15},4002, alive=1014, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-127 -84 -80 -93 43 11 68 -77 -65 -49 47 -119 -59 -120 40 19 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:14 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster memberAdded
INFO: Replication member added:org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4002,{10, 0, 2, 15},4002, alive=1016, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-127 -84 -80 -93 43 11 68 -77 -65 -49 47 -119 -59 -120 40 19 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]

Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster messageReceived
FINE: Assuming clocks are synched: Replication for GET-ALL-localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0 took=64 ms.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager messageReceived
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: Received SessionMessage of type=(SESSION-GET-ALL) from [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4002,{10, 0, 2, 15},4002, alive=5054, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-127 -84 -80 -93 43 11 68 -77 -65 -49 47 -119 -59 -120 40 19 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager handleGET_ALL_SESSIONS
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: start unloading sessions
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager sendSessions
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: unloading sessions complete
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager sendSessions
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0] send all session data.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager handleGET_ALL_SESSIONS
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0] send all session data transfered
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager sendCreateSession
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0] send new session (8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0)
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager createSession
FINE: Created a DeltaSession with Id [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0] Total count=1
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve sendSessionReplicationMessage
FINE: Invoking replication request on /modelo_jsf-1.0/index.ud
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager requestCompleted
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: create session message [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0] delta request.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve getManager
FINE: Found Cluster DeltaManager org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager[/modelo_jsf-1.0] at /modelo_jsf-1.0
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve handlePossibleTurnover
FINE: Turnover Check time 1 msec
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve sendSessionReplicationMessage
FINE: Invoking replication request on /modelo_jsf-1.0/index.ud
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager requestCompleted
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: create session message [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0] delta request.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve getManager
FINE: Found Cluster DeltaManager org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager[/modelo_jsf-1.0] at /modelo_jsf-1.0
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve handlePossibleTurnover
FINE: Turnover Check time 1 msec
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve sendSessionReplicationMessage
FINE: Invoking replication request on /modelo_jsf-1.0/index.ud
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:26 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve getManager
FINE: Found Cluster DeltaManager org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager[/modelo_jsf-1.0] at /modelo_jsf-1.0
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:26 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve handlePossibleTurnover
FINE: Turnover Check time 0 msec
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:26 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve sendSessionReplicationMessage
FINE: Invoking replication request on /modelo_jsf-1.0/index.ud


-------SHUTDOWN TOMCAT--------

Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve stopInternal
INFO: JvmRouteBinderValve stopped
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager stopInternal
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0] is stopping
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager stopInternal
INFO: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0] expiring sessions upon shutdown
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl$ReceiverThread run
FINE: Error receiving mcast package.
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:144)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:812)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl.receive(McastServiceImpl.java:339)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl$ReceiverThread.run(McastServiceImpl.java:533)

Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster unregisterClusterValve
FINE: Invoking removeValve on StandardEngine[Catalina] with class=org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster unregisterClusterValve
FINE: Invoking removeValve on StandardEngine[Catalina] with class=org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve
```

**TOMCAT2-CLUSTER.LOG:**

```
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:12 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve setFilter
FINE: Loading request filter=
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:12 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterListener setCluster
FINE: add ClusterListener org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener@50f8360d to clusterorg.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster[Container is null]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:12 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterListener setCluster
FINE: add ClusterListener org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener@13c78c0b to clusterorg.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster[Container is null]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster startInternal
INFO: Cluster is about to start
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster registerClusterValve
FINE: Invoking addValve on StandardEngine[Catalina] with class=org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster registerClusterValve
FINE: Invoking addValve on StandardEngine[Catalina] with class=org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReceiverBase getBind
FINE: Starting replication listener on address:10.0.2.15
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReceiverBase bind
INFO: Receiver Server Socket bound to:/10.0.2.15:4002
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl setupSocket
INFO: Setting cluster mcast soTimeout to 500
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
INFO: Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start level:4
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl memberDataReceived
FINE: Mcast add member org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=8042, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:13 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster memberAdded
INFO: Replication member added:org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=8042, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:14 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
INFO: Done sleeping, membership established, start level:4
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:14 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
INFO: Sleeping for 1000 milliseconds to establish cluster membership, start level:8
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:14 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.io.BufferPool getBufferPool
INFO: Created a buffer pool with max size:104857600 bytes of type:org.apache.catalina.tribes.io.BufferPool15Impl
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:14 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector messageReceived

----- SERIA ESTA A FALHA QUE IMPEDE A REPLICA DA SESSÃO? ----------
----- THIS WOULD BE A FAILURE PREVENTS A REPLICA OF THE SESSION? ------

FINE: Received a failure detector packet:ClusterData[src=org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4002,{10, 0, 2, 15},4002, alive=1414598894083, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-127 -84 -80 -93 43 11 68 -77 -65 -49 47 -119 -59 -120 40 19 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]; id={84 35 -110 45 -81 -92 66 86 -65 -60 -61 68 -70 -31 -59 -92 }; sent=2014-10-29 14:08:14.095]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:14 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask remoteEof
FINE: Channel closed on the remote end, disconnecting

Oct 29, 2014 2:08:15 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl waitForMembers
INFO: Done sleeping, membership established, start level:8
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:17 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector messageReceived
FINE: Received a failure detector packet:ClusterData[src=org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4002,{10, 0, 2, 15},4002, alive=1414598897115, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-127 -84 -80 -93 43 11 68 -77 -65 -49 47 -119 -59 -120 40 19 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]; id={-104 48 19 83 83 -63 77 -88 -73 37 57 -66 94 46 18 47 }; sent=2014-10-29 14:08:17.273]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:17 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask remoteEof
FINE: Channel closed on the remote end, disconnecting
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager startInternal
INFO: Register manager localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0 to cluster element Engine with name Catalina
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager startInternal
INFO: Starting clustering manager at localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager findSessionMasterMember
WARNING: Found for context [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0] the replication master member [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=12550, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager getAllClusterSessions
INFO: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0], requesting session state from org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=12550, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]. This operation will timeout if no session state has been received within 60 seconds.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster messageReceived
FINE: Assuming clocks are synched: Replication for SESSION-STATE-localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0 took=28 ms.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager messageReceived
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: Received SessionMessage of type=(ALL-SESSION-DATA) from [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=12550, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager handleALL_SESSION_DATA
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: received session state data
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager handleALL_SESSION_DATA
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: session state deserialized
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster messageReceived
FINE: Assuming clocks are synched: Replication for SESSION-STATE-TRANSFEREDlocalhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0 took=113 ms.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager messageReceived
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: Received SessionMessage of type=(SESSION-STATE-TRANSFERED) from [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=12550, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager handleALL_SESSION_TRANSFERCOMPLETE
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0] received from node [[B@4743b70f:4,001] session state transfered.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:18 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager waitForSendAllSessions
INFO: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]; session state send at 10/29/14 2:08 PM received in 216 ms.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:19 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve startInternal
INFO: JvmRouteBinderValve started
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector messageReceived
FINE: Received a failure detector packet:ClusterData[src=org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4002,{10, 0, 2, 15},4002, alive=1414598902123, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-127 -84 -80 -93 43 11 68 -77 -65 -49 47 -119 -59 -120 40 19 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]; id={-128 16 -98 -3 37 -107 73 -105 -114 64 -110 -79 -58 -58 -22 -6 }; sent=2014-10-29 14:08:22.276]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask remoteEof
FINE: Channel closed on the remote end, disconnecting
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster messageReceived
FINE: Assuming clocks are synched: Replication for 8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0-1414598902874 took=6 ms.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager messageReceived
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: Received SessionMessage of type=(SESSION-MODIFIED) from [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=17555, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager handleSESSION_CREATED
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: received session [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0] created.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster messageReceived
FINE: Assuming clocks are synched: Replication for 8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0-1414598902952 took=1 ms.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager messageReceived
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: Received SessionMessage of type=(SESSION-DELTA) from [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=17555, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager handleSESSION_DELTA
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: received session [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0] delta.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster messageReceived
FINE: Assuming clocks are synched: Replication for 8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0-1414598905365 took=13 ms.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager messageReceived
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: Received SessionMessage of type=(SESSION-DELTA) from [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=20058, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:25 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager handleSESSION_DELTA
FINE: Manager [localhost#/modelo_jsf-1.0]: received session [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0] delta.
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:27 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector messageReceived
FINE: Received a failure detector packet:ClusterData[src=org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4002,{10, 0, 2, 15},4002, alive=1414598907129, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-127 -84 -80 -93 43 11 68 -77 -65 -49 47 -119 -59 -120 40 19 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]; id={-103 0 61 21 -19 10 73 72 -120 -75 101 -58 -124 18 41 -58 }; sent=2014-10-29 14:08:27.276]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:27 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask remoteEof
FINE: Channel closed on the remote end, disconnecting

------ TOMCAT1 DERRUBADO ---------
------ TOMCAT1 DOWN ---------

Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector messageReceived
FINE: Received a failure detector packet:ClusterData[src=org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4002,{10, 0, 2, 15},4002, alive=1414598912136, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-127 -84 -80 -93 43 11 68 -77 -65 -49 47 -119 -59 -120 40 19 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]; id={-127 64 28 -83 102 80 68 16 -84 4 4 107 -53 40 -97 81 }; sent=2014-10-29 14:08:32.277]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask remoteEof
FINE: Channel closed on the remote end, disconnecting
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask remoteEof
FINE: Channel closed on the remote end, disconnecting
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastServiceImpl memberDataReceived
FINE: Member has shutdown:org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=27586, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={66 65 66 89 45 65 76 69 88 ...(9)}, domain={}, ]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector memberDisappeared
INFO: Verification complete. Member disappeared[org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=27586, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={66 65 66 89 45 65 76 69 88 ...(9)}, domain={}, ]]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:32 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster memberDisappeared
INFO: Received member disappeared:org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 2, 15}:4001,{10, 0, 2, 15},4001, alive=27586, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={-86 5 -101 -18 13 68 67 106 -115 79 22 -66 41 -19 6 9 }, payload={}, command={66 65 66 89 45 65 76 69 88 ...(9)}, domain={}, ]

----- NOVA REQUISIÇÃO DA APLICAÇÃO -------
----- NEW APPLICATION REQUEST -------

Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve getManager
FINE: Found Cluster DeltaManager org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager[/modelo_jsf-1.0] at /modelo_jsf-1.0
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve handleJvmRoute

----- SESSÃO PROVENIENTE DO SERVIDOR MORTO DETECTADA. SUBSTITUIÇÃO DE NO0 PARA NO1 ------
----- SESSION FROM THE SERVER DETECTED DEAD. REPLACEMENT FROM NO0 TO NO1  -----------

FINE: Detected a failover with different jvmRoute - orginal route: [no0] new one: [no1] at session id [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve getManager
FINE: Found Cluster DeltaManager org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager[/modelo_jsf-1.0] at /modelo_jsf-1.0
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve changeRequestSessionID
FINE: Set Orginal Session id at request attriute org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteOrignalSessionID value: 8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve getManager
FINE: Found Cluster DeltaManager org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager[/modelo_jsf-1.0] at /modelo_jsf-1.0
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster send
FINE: No members in cluster, ignoring message:SESSIONID-UPDATE#localhost./modelo_jsf-1.0#8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0:8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no1
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve changeSessionID
FINE: Changed session from [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no0] to [8940FF72C70C6C7BE09E6E6239DA4402.no1]
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve handlePossibleTurnover
FINE: Turnover Check time 6 msec
Oct 29, 2014 2:08:37 PM org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve resetDeltaRequest
FINE: Cluster is standalone: reset Session Request Delta at context /modelo_jsf-1.0
```

O que eu entendi é que os tomcats estão conseguindo se comunicar e quando um cai o outro recebe a requisição com a sessão do primeiro normalmente. Parece que o problema é que o tomcat não está conseguindo receber ou ler os dados da sessão, então acaba resetando-a e o valor da variável de sessão se perde.

TOMCAT1-CLUSTER.LOG: ->    http://pastebin.com/w1TV73Qk

TOMCAT2-CLUSTER.LOG: ->    http://pastebin.com/V7C35LTL